# Vba manipulate workbook object returned

Tags: vba, function, excel, object

I can not add a worksheet to a workbook object that is returned from a function

I have the following vba code:

```
    For i = 0 To Uniq_M_Unit.Count
        'Chenge data type of collection item to string
         wrkb_nameas = CStr(Uniq_M_Unit(i))
         'Call function that creates the workbooks passing the name of the workbook as parameter
         Set wrbook = AddNewWorkbook(wrkb_nameas)
        'Add new worksheet to cuurrent opened workbook
        wrbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "XXXX"

    Next
```

And the function:

```
    Public Function AddNewWorkbook(Bar As String) As Workbook
       Set MyFunction = Workbooks.Add
       MyFunction.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\gematzab\Desktop\" & Bar & ".xlsx"
    End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to the following:

```
 Public Function AddNewWorkbook(Bar As String) As Workbook
       Set AddNewWorkbook= Workbooks.Add
       AddNewWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\gematzab\Desktop\" & Bar & ".xlsx"
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks!! Very quick